# Get user name not just ID in View List

Tags: python, django, list, listview

I am programming on web app where I am trying to display in List View user's name but I always get just id.

Here is the code of List View:

```
activities = Activity.objects \
        .annotate(day=ExtractDay('created'), month=ExtractMonth('created'), year=ExtractYear('created'))\
        .values('user', 'day', 'month', 'year') \
        .annotate(total=Count('user')) \
        .order_by('user') \
```

Getting user:

```
        for activities_data in activities:
        user = activities_data['user']
```

Code of model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I really try everything but I don't know how to deal with that.

Could you help me how to get full user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have deal with that.

I have used simple_tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def user_name(username):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=username)

    return user
```

Then in the html it looks like that:

```
{% user_name user %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your user model you can set the string represenation of the model like so

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: You put it in your models.py that contains your user model and your model has the fields first_name and last_name?

Comment: I have deal with that using simple_tag (as you can see in my answer). But thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For now you are just retrieving the object primary key, which is this id you talked about.

You should perform a search in the database looking for the correct username.

```
for activities_data in activities:
    #For each activities_data you get the related user object
    user = activities_data.objects.get(user=username)
    #From this user object you got, extract his name
    text_to_display = user.username
```

Comment: I always get error 'int' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: And now getting 'dict' object has no attribute 'objects' because of user = activities_data.objects.get(user=username)

Comment: You should modify the code I typed in order to fit in your application context. Not just copy and paste. But if you really want to do that, update your post providing the **Model** class which contains **User**.

Comment: I have deal with that using simple_tag (as you can see in my answer). But thank you for help. :)